# Jquery Syntax error missing } after function body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried this code along with other types of code yet I don't understand how to get it correctly

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //jQuery.noConflict();
    var jc_message = ['Loading...',
    'Please enter your name.',
    'Please enter your email address.',
    'Please enter a valid email address.',
    'Please enter your comment.',
    'Your comment has been added.',
    'JC error!'];

    var jc_url = $("#jc_url").val();
    var jc_url_close = $("#jc_url_close").val();
    var form, err, reply;
    function jc_scripts() {
        $('#commentform').after('<div class="jc-modal"><img src="'+jc_url_close+'" id="loading" alt="close" /><div id="error" class= "error"></div></div>');
        $('#submit').after('<img src="'+jc_url+'" id="loading" alt="'+jc_message[0]+'" />');
        $('#loading').hide();
        form = $('#commentform');
        err = $('#error');
        reply = false;
    }
    jc_scripts();
    $("#comments,#reviews").on("click",".comment-reply-link",function(){
        reply = $(this).parents('.depth-1').attr('id');
        err.empty();
    });
    $("#comments,#reviews").on("click","#cancel-comment-reply-link",function(){
        reply = false;
    });
    $("#comments,#reviews").on("submit","#commentform",function(evt){
        err.empty();
        if(form.find('#author')[0]) {
            if(form.find('#author').val() == '') {
                err.html('<span class="error">'+jc_message[1]+'</span>');
                $(".jc-modal").fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function() {$(".jc-modal").fadeOut();}, 3000);
                return false;
            }
            if(form.find('#email').val() == '') {
                err.html('<span class="error">'+jc_message[2]+'</span>');
                $(".jc-modal").fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function() {$(".jc-modal").fadeOut();}, 3000);
                return false;
            }
            var filter  = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            if(!filter.test(form.find('#email').val())) {
                err.html('<span class="error">'+jc_message[3]+'</span>');
                $(".jc-modal").fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function() {$(".jc-modal").fadeOut();}, 3000);
                if (evt.preventDefault) {evt.preventDefault();}
                return false;
            }
        } 
        if(form.find('#comment').val() == '') {
            err.html('<span class="error">'+jc_message[4]+'</span>');
            $(".jc-modal").fadeIn();
            setTimeout(function() {$(".jc-modal").fadeOut();}, 3000);
            return false;
        }
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            beforeSubmit: function() {
                $('#loading').show();
                $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
                }, // end beforeSubmit
                error: function(request){
                    err.empty();
                    var data = request.responseText.match(/<p>(.*)<\/p>/);
                    err.html('<span class="error">'+ data[1] +'</span>');
                    $(".jc-modal").fadeIn();
                    setTimeout(function() {$(".jc-modal").fadeOut();}, 3000);
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
                    return false;
                }, // end error()
                success: function(data) {
                    try {
                    // if the comments is a reply, replace the parent comment's div with it
                    // if not, append the new comment at the bottom
                    var response = $("<ol>").html(data);
                    if(reply != false) {
                        $('#'+reply).replaceWith(response.find('#'+reply));
                        $('.commentlist').after(response.find('#respond'));
                        jc_scripts();
                    } else {
                        var ctnComment= $("#comments");
                        var elBody= $("<div>"+data.replace(/[\n\r]/g, "")+"</div>");
                        //$('#comments').load(''+data+'  #comments ol li');
                        //elItems = $(''+data+'  #comments ol li');
                        elItems = elBody.find("#comments ol li");
                        title = elBody.find('#comments > h2').html();
                        //alert(elItems);
                        ctnComment.find("#comments-title").remove();
                        ctnComment.find("ol").remove();

                        var ctnListComments= $("<ol />",{"class":"commentlist comment-list"});
                        ctnListComments.append(elItems);
                        ctnComment.prepend(ctnListComments);
                        ctnComment.prepend('<h2 id="comments-title">'+title+'</h2>');
                    }
                    form.find('#comment').val('');
                    err.html('<span class="success">'+jc_message[5]+'</span>');
                    $('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $(".jc-modal").fadeIn();
                    setTimeout(function() {$(".jc-modal").fadeOut();}, 3000);
                    $("#recaptcha_reload_btn img").click();
                    $("p.stars span a").removeClass('active');
                } catch (e) {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
                    alert(jc_message[6]+'\n\n'+e);
                    $("#recaptcha_reload_btn img").click();
                }
            } 
        }); 
    return false; 
    });
    $("#comments,#reviews").on("click",".jc-modal > img",function(){
        $(".jc-modal").hide();
    });
    });
```

Is there any missed tag to close or what I've tried to close the jQuery with another `});` but I can't get it working always the same dialog box with the message

> Syntax error missing `}`

after function body

**EDIT:**

This is the function which I'm trying in wordpress comments

```
add_action('wp_head','addImages');
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','addImages');

function addImages(){ ?>
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
<input id = "jc_url" type="hidden" value="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/images/loading.gif">
<input id = "jc_url_close" type="hidden" value="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/images/close.png">
<?php }
```

Comment: share your all codes on jsfiddle or this, for checking

Comment: noone will want to read this. try reducing your code one block at a time and see if you're still seeing the error. if not, the last piece you removed should be causing the syntax error.

Comment: I tried  on jsfiddle it's getting  too many syntax errors.

Comment: When I run it worked https://jsfiddle.net/e63rnpgk/

Comment: It's working, i am not getting any } missing error.

Comment: Thanks for replies so I added also the function codes in my first post and the Im calling the jquery in the comments.php template

Comment: Dear, @Vishnu Atari try pressing jsHint button at jsfiidle to see syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax error in `if` clause which i resolved like:

```
if(form.find('#comment').val() == ' ') {
        err.html('<span class="error">'+jc_message[4]+'</span>');
        $(".jc-modal").fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function() {$(".jc-modal").fadeOut();}, 3000);
        return false;
    }
```

Your complete working: [jsFiddle Without any Syntax error](http://jsfiddle.net/h1dczmzg/)

Comment: it gives me the same error messagge maybe its a server issue because its strange I not sure why it doesnt work on my side however thanks for your time

Comment: i have corrected your syntax errors nothing else and it full fills your question.